# jQuery/JS: .one not firing because not finished setting up before action starts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-transitions

I have the following code to fade out one page and once its out, fade in the other. Im using the transitionend listener using .one from jQuery to handle this.

It does not work always, the event does not get triggered. But once i add a delay between .one and the .removeClass (which starts the animation), it works.

```
var old_pageid = parseInt( $('#container .page-show').attr( 'id').match( /\d+/)[0]);
$( '#pc'+old_pageid).one( 'transitionend', $.proxy( function() {
  $( '#pc'+old_pageid).addClass( 'display-none');
  $( '#pc'+pageid).removeClass( 'display-none');
  setTimeout( function() {
    $('#pc'+pageid).addClass( 'page-show');
  }, 50);
}, this)).removeClass( 'page-show');
```

It very looks like the first .one call takes too long. I thought that one is a blocking function. But the very last removeClass( 'page-show') gets called, but then nothing happens. The callback within the first .one is not called.

What is wrong here? How can i assure, the first .one is really finished and listening to 'transitionend' ?

Another strange thing is, the transition does not work when i add page-show immediately. But using a timeout 50ms, it works. Because page is first set display:none;, then its removed and page-show is added which makes the page opacity:1.

Comment: Please show the rest of the code on the page so that we can see the context of `old_pageid` and `pageid`

Comment: added some code on top. old_pageid is simply fetched from current page with class page-show. pageid is send along with the function call containing the code above. both pageid are correctly set, tested that part already. as i said, it works, once i add ".delay( 200)" between .one and .removeClass at the very last line.

Comment: Can you mockup a working example (e.g. in a JSFiddle)? There does not appear to be enough to go by here without seeing it in action.